# Out of memory heap size error - apache camel ftp

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am running my camel ftp to download around 10000 files from a remote linux server directory to local machine directory. I am getting an heap out of memory error as soon as it completes downloading around 2000 files. Based on the other forum threads ,  it has been suggested to use maxMessagesPerPoll. But if I set it to 1000, it downloads only 1000 files and stops. My code is pretty simple and is taken from camel ftp example

```
from("sftp://xxxxx:22//tmp/serverfolder/?stepwise=false&include=ABC*.txt}}&username=XXXX&password=XXXXX&maximumReconnectAttempts=0&delay=5s&maxMessagesPerPoll=1000")
.to(/tmp/localfolder/);
```

Comment: Try `delay=5000` instead of `delay=5s`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going down the right track talking with the guys from the forums.  However, it looks like a piece of their message was missed / missing.  Camel FTP is a "polling endpoint"  this means that it will constantly call the endpoint on a loop.  This isn't hard to configure at all and it will give you the ability to pull a few files, wait a bit and then pull more.  Ideally this will allow you to keep up with files being placed into the directory so you won't normally get a 10,000 batch of files to move.  You can move a few hundred every couple seconds.

Documentation:

http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html

http://camel.apache.org/ftp.html

**IMPORTANT NOTE FROM FTP DOCS:** See File2 as all the options there also applies for this component.

http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Information from the file2 documentation

```
Property    Default    Description
delay       500        Milliseconds before the next poll of the file/directory.
```

This simply means that you can pick up a few files every couple seconds or minutes instead of trying to move all 10k at once.  Also remember when using this option you typically would never have a 10k build up unless you only started your camel route once in a while.

**IMPORTANT NOTE 2:** FTP Consumer does not support concurrency

Just keep this in mind.  You won't be able to just add a bunch of threads to increase performance so its important to keep your component constantly going if you want to handle lots of files.  Ideally constantly consuming them rather than a once a day batch load is preferred.